# Read data from a text file and embed it to an HTML webpage . How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a HTML file like this..

```
<html>
<body>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
<td>Some Fixed text here</td>
<td id="data">---here data as per values in external text file---</td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Now i have a text file **data.txt** in same directory of the *index.html* file.

I have to read the text file using some **scripts** and  put fixed innerHTML in the **id=data** as per values in the *first character of the text file*.

Such as

for  **0** in first character , innerHTML=`<div style="color:red; border:2px dotted blue;">Alpha</div>`

for **1** in first character, innerHTML=`<div>Beta</div>`

for **2** in first character, innerHTML=`<div>Gamma<span>more text</span></div>`

etc...

I found various scripts which used jquery,ajax. I tried those, and they didn't work for me. As I have not much knowledge about those technologies I cannot find the problem. Can anyone help me to make a script using  javascript or similar?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery solution for plain text file, checking first character of text in file:

```
$( function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data.txt',
        type: 'get',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.substr(0,1) == 0)
                {$("#data").html('<div style="color:red; border:2px dotted blue;">Alpha</div>');}
            if (data.substr(0,1) == 1)
                {$("#data").html('<div>Beta</div>');}
        },
    });
});
```

You just have to add all other conditions you want to check for.

**Edit:**

Just in case you don't know, you have to add this to your html document if you use jQuery code.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Load and store the text into a var in **JavaScript** :

```
var text = new XMLHttpRequest();
text.open('GET', '/data.txt');
text.onreadystatechange = function() {
  alert(text.responseText);
}
text.send();
```

Or load into the page using **PHP** (easier IMHO) :

```
<div><p><?php include('data.txt'); ?></p></div>
```